# Rails 3: Join Table with additional attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have a simple cart system that I have been working on for a little while for an application and am needing a little help in trying to figure out how to update a particular attribute in a join table (Between Order and Products).

Here is the code:

```
def add_product_to_cart
        @product = Product.by_client(current_client).first 
        @order = current_order
        unless @order.products.exists? :id => @product.id
            @order.products << @product
        end
    end
```

I am trying to update a particular attribute when I update the `@order.products`...

This is what I am trying to do:
`@order.products << @product` --> When this happens I need to update a `:price` attribute..

Anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Order
  has_many :products
  def price
    products.sum(:price)
  end
end
```

Just off the top of my head.  Here's the sum reference:

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000296

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. The `:price` column exists in the orders_products table. I need to update that column.

Comment: I get that, actually. I also could have been clearer. My suggestion was that you could calculate price when needed on the fly. I don't know offhand how I would update the price in anything other than a `before_save`, which wouldn't work for `<<`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the suggestion! That will actually come in handy with another piece of this puzzle!

Comment: Glad it was somewhat helpful at least. It looks like this answer might actually be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332243/counter-cache-for-total-items/5334639#5334639

Answer (score 1):

Desire to put attributes into join table may be a sign of missing model. You can promote join table into model, say `OrderItem`, by adding primary key to it. HABTM associations in `Order` and `Product` then become `has_many through` associations. The new model would be a good place for setting up callback which populates `price` attribute. It can also unlock additional benefits, like time-stamping items and making them `act_as_list`, etc.